# Firemonkey ListView OnMouseDown event

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

in VCL we can use this ( To get a ListItem ):

```
TForm.ListView1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); 
var 
  li: TListItem; 
  lv : TListView; 
begin 
  lv := TListView(Sender); 
  li := lv.GetItemAt(X, Y);  // we get our ListItem 
end;
```

But with the Firemonkey ListView i don't see any GetItemAt function .

So please how can we get a ListItem by using OnMouseDown event of the ListView ( in firemonkey ) .

many thanks .

Comment: You can use the `Selected` property.

Comment: `ObjectAtPoint` perhaps ?

Comment: I want to use this to be able to select an item even with the OnMouseDown event .

Comment: @TLama `ObjectAtPoint` returns IControl as i see in the FMX.ListView unit .

Answer (score 1):

There's no ready made solution to find the item with OnMouseDown. I suggest you use OnItemClick instead:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
```

which gives you a reference to the item

Comment: i know about this event , all what i want is to be able to select an item by right click : `if Button=TMouseButton.mbRight ` .
thank you .

Answer (score 0):

As Tom said, there's no ready made solution. But if you can live with FMX source changes you can insert that into FMX.ListView

```
function TListViewBase.GetItemAt(P: TPointF):TListItem;
var
  ItemAt: Integer;
begin
  ItemAt := FindItemAbsoluteAt(Round(FScrollViewPos + P.Y - (LocalRect.Top + FSideSpace)));
  if (ItemAt >= 0) and (ItemAt < Adapter.Count) then
    Result := Adapter[ItemAt]
  else
    Result := nil
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the TListViewItem on rigth click by searching if the current position of the mouse is inside the item rect.

I use only Y because all my itmes are only text but you can extend the complexity by using the X value too.

In this example i set the selected item with the rightclick.

```
procedure TForm2.lwPlayListMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
var
  I: Integer;
  rct: TRectF;
begin
 if ssRight in Shift then
  for I := 0 to lwPlayList.Items.Count-1 do
   Begin
     rct := lwPlayList.GetItemRect(I);
     if ( rct.Bottom >= Y) and (Y >= rct.Top ) then
      Begin
        lwPlayList.ItemIndex := I;
        lwPlayList.Selected := lwPlayList.Items[I];
      End;
   End;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, ListView.ItemIndex property is correct, so you can rely on it. But you can write OnItemClick event, to simply grab AItem.Index in a field and then use it in your double click event.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  FClickedIndex := AItem.Index;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
  SelectedItemText: string;  
begin
  // it is correct as well  
  //Index := ListView1.ItemIndex;
  Index := FClickedIndex;
  SelectedItemText := ListView1.Items[Index].Objects.TextObject.Text;
  // do something with the index, item or text.
end;
```